# Update query with Autonumber field in ms access from VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

How i update data with Autonumber field in ms access from VB.NET. I try this code for update. But nothing change.

```
Private Sub BTNUPDATE_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BTNUPDATE.Click
    Try
        getConnect()

        Dim strSQL As String
        Dim iCount As Integer
        strSQL = " UPDATE DEPARTMENT SET [DEPART]=@DEPART,[DEP_DSCRPTN]=@DEP_DSCRPTN WHERE [DEP_ID] = @DEP_ID"
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSQL, Conn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DEP_ID", CInt(DEPID.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DEPART", CMBDEPT.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DEP_DSCRPTN", TXTDESC.Text)
        Conn.Open()
        iCount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Conn.Close()
        If iCount > 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully!", "Update", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            If Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                BTNCLEAR.PerformClick()
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox("No record was inserted")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("ERROR: " + ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Update")
    Finally

        BTNCLEAR.PerformClick()
    End Try

End Sub
```

In database `DEP_ID` is Autonumber. and `DEPID` is a label box to retrieve `DEP_ID`. Actually the label is hidden in the form. I try the above code. But nothing change in database. Please check my code and correct me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the order in which you declare the parameters.
The OleDb provider doesn't use the parameter name, but its position in the collection

In your query the @DEP_ID parameter is the latest one, but in the collection you declare it as first.
You are lucky if the query has not updated the wrong record.

```
    strSQL = " UPDATE DEPARTMENT SET [DEPART]=@DEPART,[DEP_DSCRPTN]=@DEP_DSCRPTN WHERE [DEP_ID] = @DEP_ID"
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSQL, Conn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DEPART", CMBDEPT.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DEP_DSCRPTN", TXTDESC.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DEP_ID", CInt(DEPID.Text)
```